# problem with image rotation

Tags: floats, rotating

I am facing a weird problem. I am trying to include an eps file into my thesis. The code I am using is as follows:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twoside]{ce}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{url}
 \begin{document}

 \newpage

 \begin{figure}[H]
     \includegraphics[angle=45,width=0.75\textwidth]{images/final.eps}
      \caption{Final image}
      \label{fig:final}
  \end{figure} %working code, page does not rotate. just image rotates.


 \end{document}
```

This code works. But when I rotate the image with 90 deg., the image rotates but the page also rotates. If I rotate it by an angle less than or equal to 45, then the page does not rotate and only the image rotates. When the rotation is greater than 45, the page and image both rotate.

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
     \includegraphics[angle=46,width=0.75\textwidth]{images/final.eps}
      \caption{Final image}
      \label{fig:final}
  \end{figure} % non-working code, image as well as page rotates.

 \begin{figure}[H]
     \includegraphics[angle=90,width=0.75\textwidth]{images/final.eps}
      \caption{Final image}
      \label{fig:final}
  \end{figure} % non-working code, image as well as page rotates.
```

I want to rotate the image by 90 deg but not the page. Since each page has a header, page rotation is annoying me. Due to rotation of the page, the header comes to the right side, instead of being on the top. Can somebody help?

Comment: sure, i have edited the question.

Comment: Can you make the `eps` file available for download?

Comment: ce is a template done by my faculty. I think it is a custom template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably you are using Ghostscript/ps2pdf. It has the feature that it inspects the page to determine in which orientation the page if viewed best. This can be turned off:

```
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None
```

(In the command shell of Windows you might need `#` instead of `=`).

Edit: Value fixed (thanks Higgs Boson).

Comment: `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` or `-dAutoRotatePages#false`? I used the former and it works.

Comment: Bingo! it worked! Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: Another method by invoking ghostscript directly: run `gswin**c -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.ps` where `**` is either `32` or `64` depending which one you have installed. No need to change `=` to `#` for sure.