# Q: How to rotate the figure without rotating the page

Tags: texmaker, rotating

I'm trying to insert a figure in landscape format by using the rotate package. The resulting pdf show that the figure and the page were rotated to landscape. I found a solution on tex.stackexchange that recommends the use of

```
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None
```

(found here : [problem with image rotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65072/problem-with-image-rotation/65076#65076?newreg=844f2ff5d83046828c7a1b4772509229) )
to prevent the page from rotating.

I'm using TexMaker and I'm not sure where to insert the above line of code to correct the rendering of the figure.

Comment: If you want only the figure to be rotated, you can use `\includegraphics[angle=90]{file}` from [this link](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=9323)

Comment: I tried both the solutions listed there (angle=90...) and sideways, both result in rotation of the page along with the graphics..

Comment: If you just put `angle` in includegraphics none of the page settings are changed, try testing different pdf viewers perhaps one is trying to be too clever and auto-rotating at the wrong time.

Comment: Send us a MWE with the `angle` options.